# NSMutableArray Exc_Bad_Access

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I only have this code in m. file

```
 NSMutableArray * arrayOfBools;

   arrayOfBools=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];

NSNumber *ijk =(NSNumber*) 9;

       [arrayOfBools addObject:ijk];
```

Get error o this  [arrayOfBools addObject:ijk];

Comment: Obj-C doesn't automatically convert between different types, and what you're doing with `(NSNumber*)` is called typecasting, which unless you know what you're doing, should be avoided. In this example, you're casting an integer into a pointer, with disastrous results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare and set an NSNumber like this: `NSNumber *ijk =(NSNumber*) 9;`.
This will set it to an integer (9).

Use this:

```
NSNumber *ijk = [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
```

Answer (score 1):

The third line, the declaration of the NSNumber is incorrect. if you are attempting to wrap a bool into a NSNumber, use `NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];`